# How would you plot a pandas series of floats which really stand for a categorical variable?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I am learning Pandas exploring a Google Play installs dataset on kaggle:

https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps

One of the columns is "Installs" and I have converted the values from the original Object type to Float to perform basic descriptive statistics but when I look at the content:

```
0.000000e+00      15
1.000000e+00      67
5.000000e+00      82
1.000000e+01     386
5.000000e+01     205
1.000000e+02     719
5.000000e+02     330
1.000000e+03     907
5.000000e+03     477
1.000000e+04    1054
5.000000e+04     479
1.000000e+05    1169
5.000000e+05     539
1.000000e+06    1579
5.000000e+06     752
1.000000e+07    1252
5.000000e+07     289
1.000000e+08     409
5.000000e+08      72
1.000000e+09      58
Name: Installs, dtype: int64
```

It is clear that Google does not give an exact number but rather a "bin".

Plotting it with this basic command:

```
apps['Installs'].plot.bar()
```

yields an almost unintelligible image.

Suggestions for a more readable presentation?

Suggestions to graphically show the different distribution of a subset of the data (e.g. only the "Medical" app category data)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to group those bins to clear the clutter and sum the corresponding values for each of the bin (or whatever measure you want to use). Currently there are too many bins so its messing up the whole visual.

Comment: Good suggestion Shiv thank you that I will try. I guess I could keep the 0 values (no installs) and then halve the others keeping one value for each order of magnitude ...

Comment: Yes, but keep the bins as few as possible.